# Probability problem with matrices

Tags: probability, matrices

I have solved a problem some time ago and forgot the derivation of my approach.
The problem goes like this:

There is a wheel of fortune that has four sectors of equal size with the colors red, yellow, green and blue. 
The
Matching game board consists of 4 fields in the same colors. At the beginning of the game
the game board is empty, which I have defindet  $S_0$ for Status Zero.

With the wheel of fortune some colours are determined.
If the field with this color is empty, it will be covered with a stone.

If there is
already a stone in this field, then the stone is removed, so
the field is then empty again.

The game ends when all 4 fields are filled and with stones.

Now I would like to determine the probability, that the game ends after exactly 12 rotations of the wheel.

My approach:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0.25 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        1 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0.75 & 0 & 0.75 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0.25 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
 0  \\
 0  \\
 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

This Matrix $A$ shows all probabilities for $S_0$ to $S_4$ of the game and $B$ is a vector to show how it develops with $S_0=1$ as the game begins with no stones. My idea is to generate the matrix $A^{12}*B$ which shows that $S_0=0.4168$ and the matrix $A^{11}*B$ which shows that $S_0=0.3486$ and to then calculate the difference which is $0.4168-0.3486=0.0682$

As already mentioned: I have solved this problem a long time ago and the solution is correct, but I have forgotten my idea behind this approach and how I've derived it.

Can someone explain why this is correct?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an improvement: If you replace the $1$ in the bottom right corner by $0$, you don't have to subtract two results, you can just directly take the bottom entry from $A^{12}B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Markov chain.  The entries in the vector $A^kB$ give the probabilities of being in  state $0,1,2,3,4$ after $k$ moves, so $A^{12}B$ gives the probabilities after $12$ moves.  The last component of this vector is $\approx.4168.$

Of course, the game might have ended before the twelfth move, so you subtract the probability that the game is over after $11$ moves.

To see that $AB$ gives the probabilities after one move is just a matter of writing down the matrix product.  Then you just apply $A$ to result inductively for general $k$.